# safely terminating a thread in Meyers Singleton

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, singleton

I have a boost thread running inside a Meyers' Singleton. It happily runs for the duration of my program.

When my Singleton's destructor is called (when the program is loaded out of memory) I set a flag so that the thread should exit it's loop and fire off a call to `thread.join()`.

Now, on Windows, calling `thread.join()` causes a bad access exception. But on Mac, ***not*** calling `thread.join()` throws a bad access exception!

Can anyone shed any light on this difference in behaviour between these 2 operating systems, and/or provide instructions on how to safely terminate my thread?

***edit: this code works on both Mac and Windows if I run it in a simple command line application. It doesn't matter if I call `myThread.join()` or not!***

Running as shared library exhibits the issue... the memory exception on Mac happens when I try and reload the dylib a second time and I omit the call to `myThread.join()`,

example:

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"

class MeyersSingleton
{
public:
    MeyersSingleton()
    :   threadShouldExit(false),
        myThread(boost::ref(*this) ) {
    }

    ~MeyersSingleton() {
        threadShouldExit = true;
        myThread.join();
    }

    static MeyersSingleton& getInstance() {
        static MeyersSingleton singletonInstance;
        return singletonInstance;
    }

    void operator()() {
        while(!threadShouldExit) {
            // my busy worker thread...
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
private:
    bool threadShouldExit;
    boost::thread myThread;
};
```

Comment: Just for completeness, what happens in Linux? :D

Comment: The difference is most likely due to undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: the order of destruction of the static objects may be the origin of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: if you have a *simple command line application* please include it in your question, as currently written it isn't a [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

- `sleep()` is not safe in multi-threaded applications because it uses `SIGALRM`. Use `nanosleep()` instead.
- `threadShouldExit` is changed with no locks held, so it should be a C++11 atomic, or use [atomic functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) to read and set its value.